# (Obvious?) Half-Space Poisson Kernel Estimate

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

In Stein's *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*, Theorem 1 (a) of Chapter 8 (pg. 197) he makes the claim without proof that the Poisson Kernel for the half-space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_{+}$
$$P_{y}(x)=\frac{c_{n}y}{(|x|^{2}+y^{2})^{(n+1)/2}}$$
majorizes its $t$ translation $P_{y}(x-t)$ with absolute constant $A_{\alpha}$ (depending only on $\alpha$, which we are free to fix) so long as $|t|<\alpha y.$  That is, with $t$ so restricted,
$$P_{y}(x-t)\leq A_{\alpha}P_{y}(x).$$

The setting here is $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$.  $c_{n}$ is just a constant depending on the dimension $n$ (the volume of the unit ball I believe).  $x$ is regarded as being in $\partial\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_{+}$ and $y$ the perpendicular component of a point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$

This does not seem at all obvious to me as he says.  Furthermore, this assertion is markedly similar to my previous (still unanswered) question here [Some Scaling Estimate for Heat Kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593737/some-scaling-estimate-for-heat-kernel) (notationally, just change $y$ to $\sqrt{y}$, add an aditional constant $\beta$ for $\beta y$ and then interchange the roles of $y$ and $t$).  I guess I am just having a hard time understanding and proving these estimates and it's causing me some problems with what I'm trying to do.  Any help is appreciated.

---

[image]

---

So let us cancel $y$ and $c_{n}$ and raise both sides of the inequality to the $(n+1)/2$ power and put $C_{\alpha}=A_{\alpha}^{(n+1)/2}$.  Then we have to show

$$\frac{1}{|x|^{2}+y^{2}-2x\cdot t+|t|^{2}}\leq\frac{C_{\alpha}}{|x|^{2}+y^{2}}$$
when $|t|\leq\alpha y.$  We obviously have to somehow control the $|t|^{2}-2x\cdot t$ term and adjust $C_{\alpha}$ accordingly, but I'm not sure how to do this because of $x$, which is unrestricted.

Comment: Can you elaborate if $x$ or $y$ is regarded as a constant?

Comment: I believe $y>0$ is allowed to vary.  $\alpha$ is the only parameter fixed, and $A$ is only allowed to depend on $\alpha$.

Comment: In other words $x$ is fixed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking closer at the passage in the text and it looks like $y$ is actually held fixed.  The reason I was tempted to say it is not is that in my linked question the equivalent of $y$ there (i.e. $t$) is allowed to vary, but that is why (I think) there is the additional constant involved in the estimate, namely $\beta$.  So anyway, yes, $y$ is fixed.

Comment: I added the page where the theorem/proof appears.  See (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real $x$, $y$, and $t$,
$$
      x^{2}+y^{2} = ((x-t)+t)^{2}+y^{2} = (x-t)^{2}+2(x-t)t+t^{2}+y^{2}.
$$
For real $a$ and $b$, one has $ab \le |ab| \le \frac{1}{2}(a^{2}+b^{2})$. For $\rho > 0$, one also has $2ab \le \rho a^{2}+\frac{1}{\rho}b^{2}$. Hence, if $\alpha > 0$, $y \ge 0$, and $|t| \le \alpha y$,
$$
      x^{2}+y^{2} \le (x-t)^{2}+\alpha(x-t)^{2}+\frac{1}{\alpha}t^{2}+y^{2} \le  (1+\alpha)\{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2})\}.
$$
Finally, in terms of the Poisson kernel $P_{y}(x)=\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ for the upper half-plane,
$$    P_{y}(x-t)=\frac{y}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}} \le \frac{A_{\alpha}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=A_{\alpha}P_{y}(x),\;\;\; y > 0,\;|t| \le \alpha y,\; x \in\mathbb{R}.
$$
The argument can be modified to work for Poisson kernels on higher-dimensional half spaces.

BTW: This is also related to the heat kernel issue. It is possible to study non-tangential limits as $t \rightarrow 0$ for solutions of the heat equation, or to study non-tangential limits of harmonic functions on a half-space as one approaches the boundary of the half space.

One thing that can be shown is this: if $\phi(x,y)$ is a bounded harmonic function on the upper half-plane where $y > 0$, then $\phi(x,0+)=\lim_{y\downarrow 0}\phi(x,y)$ exists for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and
$$
               \phi(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x,0+)y}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}\,dt =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x,0+)\left[\frac{1}{t-(x+iy)}-\frac{1}{t-(x-iy)}\right]dt.
$$
The non-tangential limits of $\phi$ also exist, and equal the orthogonal limits.

Comment: Should the second centered equation have an extra $t^2$ in the middle expression?
$x^{2}+y^{2} \le (x-t)^{2}+\alpha(x-t)^{2}+\frac{1}{\alpha}t^{2}+\color{red}{t^2}+y^{2} \le  (1+\alpha)\left((x-t)^{2}+y^{2})\right)$
If so, how would this new inequality be coaxed into the desired form? (I don't see how the "$\ldots \le (1+\alpha)\left((x-t)^{2}+y^{2})\right)$" can still hold.)

Comment: @spenceryue : Start with the first inequality, then combine with the substitutions listed in the following sentence.

Comment: What I meant was, if I'm not mistaken I believe you have omitted a $\color{red}{t^2}$ in the process of substituting $2(x-t)t^2 \le \alpha(x-t)^2 + \frac{1}{\alpha}t^2$. The $\color{red}{t^2}$ in $(x-t)^2 + 2(x-t)t + \color{red}{t^2} + y^2$ at the end of the the first line got dropped.

Comment: @spenceryue : Once you get down to $C_{\alpha}(x-t)^2+D_{\alpha}y^2$, then use a constant $A_{\alpha}$ that is is the maximum of $C_{\alpha},D_{\alpha}$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, in particular, I think it should be $C_\alpha = (1 + \alpha)$ and $D_\alpha = \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1$ instead of $D_\alpha = 1 + \alpha$ as written here. (Because $\frac{1}{\alpha}t^2 + \color{red}{t^2} + y^2 = (\alpha + \alpha^2 + 1)y^2$.) But I see now that this doesn't affect the argument significantly. I just wanted to point out the typo/omission.

Comment: @spenceryue : It's a good thing to correct these things. I appreciate it, and will will fix the constants.

Answer (score 2):

I think the statement should be understood from the perspective of Possion kernel. The classical Possion kernel is given by

$$P_{y}(x)=\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}},u(x+iy)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}P_{y}(x-t)f(t)dt$$(see the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel)

In other words at here both $x,y$ are fixed and only $t$ is allowed to changed. Here we have to show
$$\frac{1}{(|x-t|^{2}+y^{2})^{n+1}}\le C\frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{n+1}},\forall t, |t|<\alpha y$$
Notice Stein's book has a typo where he wrote $f(z)dx$, which should be $f(z)dz$ instead. Now for fixed $x$, the maximum and minimum for $|x-t|^{2}$ is fixed as well. So the above statement must be true since the left hand side is bounded.